# Fixed layout positions in CSS only as it scrolls up (snap to top)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I am not sure if there is a specific name for the behaviour I want to achieve (in the title).

I'll give an example: on the issues pages on GitHub (e.g. [here](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/UsefulViews/issues/28)), where the right column (with information about labels, milestones, assignees) has a fixed position, but only when you scroll down. In other words, it seems to have a `static` layout as you are scrolling it at first, but then snaps to the top and acts like a `fixed` layout as you scroll further.

Another example would be how the left and right columns (navigation and contents) on some [Google Developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView) behave in a similar way I have described above.

I hope my question isn't too vague, and although I am aware of `position: fixed;` in CSS, I am unsure of how to adapt it to achieve the desired effects above.

Comment: There is no CSS-selector for scroll-position or viewport-related bounds-checking. These kind of effects are usually achieved with javascript. Are you interested in script-solutions?

Comment: @jayms Yes, that would be fine thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding and removing classes on scroll with Jquery or javascript I am using jquery here.  Also in the following example I added a class to stop the sidebar when it hits the footer but if you just want it to keep going you can remove that part and just keep the sidebar scrolling.

Here is a fiddle [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/7n8w4xbw/)

I have put this in a full html page so you can just copy and paste it into your text editor so you can see it in action.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    body{padding: 0;margin: 0;color:#fff;}
    header{background: blue;height: 100px;text-align: center;}
    footer{background: blue;height: 1000px;text-align: center;}

    .content-container{position: relative;}
    .main-content{margin-left:200px;background: purple;height: 1000px;text-align:center;}
    .sidebar{
      position:absolute;
      top:0;left:0;
      background: green;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      text-align:center;
      /*like to add the following to stop from jumpy scrolling in webkit browsers*/
      -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
      backface-visibility:hidden; 
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      transform: translateZ(0);
    }
    .sidebar.sidebar-fixed{position:fixed;}
    .sidebar.sidebar-stop{position: absolute;bottom:0;top:auto;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>Header</header>
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
      <div class="main-content">Main Content</div>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     var contentTop = $('.content-container').offset().top;
     var sidebarHeight = $('.sidebar').height();
     var contentBottom = $('footer').offset().top - sidebarHeight;
     $(window).scroll(function(){
       var scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();
       //starts the fixed sidebar
       if(scrolltop >= contentTop){
         $('.sidebar').addClass("sidebar-fixed");
       }else{
         $('.sidebar').removeClass("sidebar-fixed");
       }
       //stops the fixed sidebar
       if(scrolltop >= contentBottom){
         $('.sidebar').addClass("sidebar-stop");
       }else{
         $('.sidebar').removeClass("sidebar-stop");
       }
     });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it seems to be having no effect when I implement it myself. Similarly, if I take the HTML, CSS and JS code and put them in files on my own computer (as opposed to JSFiddle), it also has no effect. Could I be missing something?

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that I used jquery so I'm not sure if you loaded jquery or not before the script.  I have edited my answer and included the full html markup so you can just copy and paste it to see it working.

Comment: Thanks for the update - much appreciated. Unfortunately I can't try it out now as I'm literally about to go to sleep, but I'll let you know if you update resolves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > /* number of pixels from top */){
        $("/* sticky div id or class */").css("position", "fixed");
    }
});
```